# Rails, in the model is there a way to provide a dif since the last update?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

given a model like:

```
class SentenceItem < ActiveRecord::Base

  after_update :send_changes

  def send_changes
     #### Is it possible to do a diff here with dirty/changed? Showing what's changed since the last save?
  end

end
```

And that the sentence modle has a text field.

Is it possible to do a diff here with dirty/changed? Showing what's changed since the last save?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is a way. From the [ActiveModel::Dirty](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Dirty) documentation:

A newly instantiated object is unchanged:

```
person = Person.find_by_name('Uncle Bob')
person.changed?       # => false
```

Change the name:

```
person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed?       # => true
person.name_changed?  # => true
person.name_was       # => 'Uncle Bob'
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bob']
person.name = 'Bill'
person.name_change    # => ['Uncle Bob', 'Bill']
```

Which attributes have changed?

```
person.name = 'Bob'
person.changed        # => ['name']
person.changes        # => { 'name' => ['Bill', 'Bob'] }
```

Comment: Great answer, very thorough and straightforward overview of the `Dirty` module.